# Outlook VSTO - Update Periodic AppointmentItem Parent

Tags: c#, com, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook Add-In (plugin) and I'm basically working with Outlook appointment items (`Outlook.AppointmentItem`).

Each time someone create, save or update an occurrence of a periodic appointment item, i need to get the main `AppointmentItem` (the parent) and add or update an `UserProperty`.

Until here, it's more or less working. That means i get the parent and i can manipulate his `UserProperties` but it doesn't work every time.

If the periodic appointment has 5 occurrences and for each references i update something, I'm expecting to modify the `UserProperties` of the parent 5 times. But that doesn't work and sometimes the parent his old "state".

Technically, in the `Item_Write` I get the parent and change his `UserProperties`. And just before the last bracket of the `Item_Write` i check the UserProperties of the parent and they contain what I'm expecting. But in the "Close" method who is called just after the `Item_Write` when i check if the parent still contain the expected `UserProperties` I see that they haven't been updated and they still are in the same state that before.

After some research, i saw a lot of people (even the Msdn) saying that i should use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`. I tried that and now I'm releasing the parent (and other `COM` object) every time i call them. Maybe I'm not using it well and because of that, it's still doesn't work.

The problem seems to appear between the `Item_Write` and the `Close`. After leaving `Item_Write` the `UserProperties` are okay, but when i enter the `Close` they are not anymore.
Does anyone ever have any similar problem?

Should i use `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` on the parent just before the end of `Item_Write`?

I you think it's better or it will be easier to understand what's going on by looking at some part of my code, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it is most definitely related to not properly releasing objects.  Read the Remarks section in the documentation for the AppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern method as it describes your situation perfectly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868441.aspx.

Comment: I also think that the problem is related to some object not properly released.

I had already read that article, but thanks to you, when i read it this time I noticed the Exceptions property on the AppointmentItem and with that property i could do what i was willing to but in another way (so the probleme described on top is not appearing anymore).
Thanks